# Elasticsearch on LAN not connecting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have an elasticsearch running on a server (ubuntu) hosted on a local machine in our network.  We have used it for testing and want to connect from local computers.  The machines lan ip is 192.168.1.100.  My ip is 192.168.1.54. It is running when I do

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "norrath",
  "cluster_uuid" : "0EqCQH1ZTSGzOOdq_Sf7EQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "7299dc3",
    "build_date" : "2018-02-07T19:34:26.990113Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When I try from my machine..

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.100:9200'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.100 port 9200: Connection refused
```

First thing I did was follow digital oceans instructions and changed

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Using netstat -atun

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

UFW status

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I have tried multiple config file changes..

```
#http.cors.enabled: true
#http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0
#transport.tcp.port: 9300
#http.port: 9200
network.host:  0.0.0.0
#network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
#network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

Still not able to connect over lan.

Comment: setting the IP of the host in the `network.host` config should do it. you'll need to restart the service once you have updated the config.

`network.host
The node will bind to this hostname or IP address and publish (advertise) this host to other nodes in the cluster. Accepts an IP address, hostname, a special value, or an array of any combination of these..
`

Find more details [here:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings)

Answer (score 0):

After examining my netstat output, I realized it  is listening for tcp6 requests but not ipv4.  Changing my curl request to the inet6 address, and setting up tcp/udp rather than tcp only fixed our issue.